# How to get the token from moodle webservice?

Tags: android

```
package com.exmple.moodle_webservice;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button token;

    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    
    // Progress Dialog
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        token=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        
        token.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                
                String result = null;
                
                try {
                    
                    result = new getToken().execute("").get();
                    
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.e("Error--->",e.toString());
                }
                
                Log.e("result--->",result);
                
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }



class getToken extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        String getToken = "http://10.0.2.2:80/moodle/login/token.php";
        
    //String getToken = "http://localhost/moodle/login/token.php?                   username=niranga&password=S12345s@&service=moodle_mobile_app";


        
        // Building Parameters
         List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "niranga"));
         params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "S12345s@"));
         params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("service", "moodle_mobile_app"));
        
         
                    // getting JSON string from URL
         JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(getToken, "GET", params);
        
         Log.e("json--->",json.toString());
        
         try {
             
            return json.getString("token");
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("Errorrr--->",e.toString());
            
        }
        
        return null;
        
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        
    }
    
    
}
}
```

My JSONParser class:

```
package com.exmple.moodle_webservice;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET method
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
                       try {
            
            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
                
            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
                
                //Log.e("get Entity result--->",is.toString());
            }           
            

        
        } catch (Exception e) {
            
            Log.e("Error-------->>>",e.toString());
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

When I try to get the token from moodle webservice I get error:

### LogCat

```
03-17 05:21:22.285: E/json--->(2008): {"stacktrace":null,"error":"Invalid url or port.","debuginfo":null,"errorcode":null}
03-17 05:21:22.295: E/Errorrr--->(2008): org.json.JSONException: No value for token
03-17 05:21:22.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2008): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-17 05:21:22.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2008): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
03-17 05:21:22.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2008):     at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
03-17 05:21:22.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2008):     at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:231)
03-17 05:21:22.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2008):     at com.exmple.moodle_webservice.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:64)
03-17 05:21:22.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2008):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
03-17 05:21:22.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2008):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
03-17 05:21:22.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2008):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-17 05:21:22.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2008):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-17 05:21:22.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2008):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-17 05:21:22.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2008):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-17 05:21:22.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2008):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-17 05:21:22.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2008):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-17 05:21:22.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2008):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-17 05:21:22.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2008):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-17 05:21:22.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2008):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can I get the token from moodle?

Answer (score 1):

Clear steps for [creating web service token in moodle](http://docs.moodle.org/24/en/Using_web_services).

Please go through the above mentioned url. Reply to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same problem. To resolve it I had to edit the following line inside the `config.php` file located in the Moodle root folder (`/var/www/moodle/config.php` in my case, on Ubuntu 12.10):

```
$CFG->wwwroot   = 'http://10.0.2.2/moodle';
```

You'll have to use the IP address which your device will see as the host of the Moodle web server (in case of the emulator, the host machine is seen at 10.0.2.2).